# Correct behavior of the Excel.CloseBehavior enum when trying to close a workbook in the web

Tags: ms-office, office-js, excel-addins, ms-office-addin

I'm trying to close a workbook in the web and have the browser tab just close. I'm making the following calls to do this:

```
        Excel.run(async context => {
            context.workbook.isDirty = false;
        });            
        Excel.run(async context => {
            context.workbook.close(Excel.CloseBehavior.skipSave); //.save);
        });
```

But when I do this, I get a prompt saying I'm going to be re-directed to the Office 365 home page. If I just try and close the page I get prompted about asking if I'm sure I want to close the page. I've tried changing the .close call to use the Excel.CloseBehavior.save enum but that doesn't behave any differently.

Is there a way to close the workbook that won't prompt me to go to the Office 365 home page and also close the browser tab?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for reaching us.  Looks like current API doesn't meet your needs.

For new feature request, we would like to suggest you go to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform and see if your question has already been asked or ask a new question. Feature requests on it are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll make that request.